# Getting a new social icon in github pages with jekyll

Tags: jekyll, minima

I'm building a [webpage](https://rjraya.github.io/) with jekyll and github pages. I would like to link to my google scholar profile in the same way I link to my github, with an icon at the bottom of the page.

I found out that this can be handled in _includes/social.html. However, I don't see any icon for scholar google. How can I get it into the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with [Academicons](https://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/).

1. Install the Academicons icons and CSS files on your server.
2. Add the academicons.css stylesheet into the page header:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/folder/css/academicons.min.css"/>
> ```

3. Add the icon to your page '_includes/social.html':

> ```
> <i class="ai ai-google-scholar"></i>
> ```